# Смена URL страниц сайта

Tags: php, .htaccess

Как преобразить URL сайта с http://site.com/news/view/1183 в http://site.com/rozvagy или http://site.com/rozvagy/1183 с помощью .htaccess, где 1183 id поста, чтобы id могло меняться при добавлении других постов, но http://site.com/rozvagy/ остается статическим? Cпасибо

Comment: URL жестко задан? Нельзя вместо http://site.com/rozvagy использовать http://site.com/rozvagy-1183 или http://site.com/1183-rozvagy ?

Comment: Нельзя, rozvagy всегда должен оставаться статическим

Comment: С помощью роутинга и регулярок.
Тут хорошо объясняется[Описание роутинга для новичков](http://maxsite.org/page/routing)

Comment: `RewriteRule rozvagy/\d+  /news/view/1183`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно попробовать отталкиваться от следующего решения

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^rozvagy/([0-9]+) /news/view/$1 [L]
```

Это преобразование будет перехватывать `http://site.com/rozvagy/1183` и отправлять его на `http://site.com/news/view/1183`. Флаг `[L]` прекратит дальнейший поиск правил преобразований.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но мне нужно немного другое, чтобы не приосходил перехват, а чтобы просто поменять url ссылок с http://site.com/news/view/1183 на http://site.com/rozvagy/1183 , с http://site.com/news/view/1184 на http://site.com/rozvagy/1184 и т.д

Comment: @InCourage поправил ответ